# how to differentiate between epic and story for an already existing software?

Tags: scrum, agile

How to decide that a requirement will be my epic or user story.I have a few enhancements from the client which cannot be grouped into something.As for example my request is adding a few informative messages.

Comment: Hi Zankhana, welcome to PM.SE! Have you looked at [What is the difference between Epic/Story/Task](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/16739/430)? It might answer your question.

Comment: Marked as duplicate to avoid a massive flow of duplicated answers as well. In case the question is not a dup, please advise and we'll happily reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways how you can decide that a requirement will be epic or user story: 
- Epic is always bigger than 1 sprint (1 sprint can't be longer than 1 month.
- A user story is one functionality in the product.
- One big user story can be split in more user stories but it is not epic.
- Epic is when you have 3 or more big User Stories who are dependent.

Epic: User Profile
User Stories: As a user, I want to have a profile picture so that I can...
I hope it was helpful.
Best regards

Comment: A few informative messages can be user stories if it can implement in one sprint.